# Can you bind to the ImageSource property of an ImageBrush with Caliburn.Micro (WinRT)?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, caliburn.micro

I was hoping to use dynamic background images with Caliburn.Micro. This is what I have tried without success.

```
<Grid>
 <Grid.Background>
   <ImageBrush x:Name="MyPhoto" /> 
 </Grid.Background>
</Grid>

//some view model
public class ImageViewModel
{
   public ImageSource MyPhoto {get;set;}
}

//Add Convention
//App.XAML.cs
...
public override void Configure()
{
  ...

        ConventionManager.AddElementConvention<ImageBrush>(ImageBrush.ImageSourceProperty, "ImageSource", "Loaded");
  ...
}
```

Is it possible to bind and ImageBrush's ImageSource with Caliburn.Micro or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure but I think `AddElementConvention` works only for `UIElement`s not `DependencyObject`s. This should work, though:

`MainPage.xaml`:

```
<Grid x:Name="MyBrush">
</Grid>
```

`MainPageViewModel.cs`:

```
public class MainPageViewModel : Screen
{
    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        MyPhoto = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/SplashScreen.png"));
    }

    public ImageSource MyPhoto { get; set; }

    public ImageBrush MyBrush
    {
        get
        {
            ImageBrush brush = new ImageBrush();
            brush.ImageSource = MyPhoto;
            return brush;
        }
    }
}
```

`App.xaml.cs`:

```
protected override void Configure()
{
    container = new WinRTContainer();
    container.RegisterWinRTServices();

    ConventionManager.AddElementConvention<Grid>(Grid.BackgroundProperty, "Background", "Loaded");
}
```

Alternatively you could do the binding by hand in XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding MyPhoto}" /> 
    </Grid.Background>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I was able to use your alternative to bind to the Grids background property. Like <Grid Background={Binding MyBrush} />. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Naming the Grid to the name of the ImageBrush while applying the custom convention also worked nicely. Thanks again!