# How do you change <path> fill in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, path

Hello fellow programmers.

I have a question, that can I change imageBrush ImageSource?
If I can, then how does it do that, I have tried many options and none of them seems not to work.

```
<Path x:Name="PathImage">
    <Path.Fill>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="pic1.png"/>
    </Path.Fill> 
</Path>
```

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13756909/can-you-bind-to-the-imagesource-property-of-an-imagebrush-with-caliburn-micro-w

Answer (score 0):

You can access the ImageBrush by casting the Path's Fill property:

```
var imageBrush = PathImage.Fill as ImageBrush;
imageBrush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri());
```

---

Even simpler would be to set the `x:Name` property directly on the ImageBrush:

```
<Path x:Name="PathImage">
    <Path.Fill>
        <ImageBrush x:Name="imageBrush" ImageSource="pic1.png"/>
    </Path.Fill> 
</Path>
```

Now the XAML parser creates a public field that you can access in code behind:

```
imageBrush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri());
```