# Binding image value to path in wpf and c#

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I am strugling to bind value to path ImageSource. I get NullReferenceError when I try to set new value.
My current code is:

In MainWindow.xaml the Path code is following

```
<Path x:Name="PPButton" Data="M110,97 L155,123
        C135,150 135,203 153,227
        L112,255 
        C80,205 80,150 110,97" 
        Stretch="none" MouseEnter="Path_MouseEnter_1" MouseLeave="Path_MouseLeave_1" >
            <Path.Fill>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding ImageSource}"/>
            </Path.Fill>
    </Path>
```

on MainWindow.xaml.cs where I get error, I commented behind Path_mouseEnter_1

```
Image image;
private void Path_MouseEnter_1(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            image.ImageSource = new Uri("/RoundUI;component/sadface.png", UriKind.Relative); // This  "An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in RoundUI.exe"
        }

        private void Path_MouseLeave_1(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            image.ImageSource = new Uri("/RoundUI;component/smileface.png", UriKind.Relative);
        }
```

Class, where binding value should take palce:

```
public class Image : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private string title;
        private Uri imageSource;

        public Uri ImageSource
        {
            get
            {
                return imageSource;
            }
            set
            {
                imageSource = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ImageSource"));
                }
            }
        }

        public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In code behind you have to use complete [Pack URIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx#Resource_File_Pack_URIs___Local_Assembly), including the `pack://application:,,,` prefix. And you should not specify `UriKind.Relative`.

```
private void Path_MouseEnter_1(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   image.ImageSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/RoundUI;component/sadface.png");
}
```

---

**Edit**: It seems that you are confusing a few things here. For now it might perhaps be easier *not to bind* the ImageBrush's `ImageSource` property, but instead set it directly in code behind, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23584337/1136211) to your previous question:

```
<Path x:Name="PPButton" ...
      MouseEnter="Path_MouseEnter_1" MouseLeave="Path_MouseLeave_1" >
    <Path.Fill>
        <ImageBrush/>
    </Path.Fill>
</Path>
```

Code behind:

```
private void Path_MouseEnter_1(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   var imageBrush = PPButton.Fill as ImageBrush;
   image.ImageSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/RoundUI;component/sadface.png");
}
```

Comment: Do I need to replace something in this code, because I still get NullReferenceError.
Does this matter, if I have my RoundUI inside "UIs"?

Comment: Don't know because you haven't said what "UIs" is. In a Pack URI like the above, "RoundUI" is the name of a referenced assembly, and "sadface.png" is an image file in the root folder of that assembly, which must have its Build Action set to `Resource`.

Comment: Where exactly do you get the NullReferenceException? Is it just because you did not assign the `image` field?

Comment: I noted, and I got it work, I looked at the solution you referred to and I had to add Binding to ImageBrush in xaml too. 
Thank you! :)